# How do I resolve conection drops in Eve Offline?

Tags: traceroute

I use Clear internet ie. wireless to get my connection. I play a game online Eve Online which has had on and off Crash To Desktop due to the connection timing out. Usually I have trouble only late at night after work but today I had no connection at 4 pm.

They ran a trace route and Im using Ping plotter to do a trace in real time. I have 100% packet loss at hop 2 and Im getting varible loss at hop 6 at `ae-72-70.ebr2.Dallas1.Level3.net`.

Also had windows send a dump to Microsoft mentioning the eve file has a problem requiring it to close.

Comment: Wireless~=Unreliable.  If you are able, get a wired connection, if you are not you may just have to accept a semi-reliable connection.

Answer (score 0):

Clear's WiMax network is pretty new, and they have a bit of a reputation of hacking things together. I wouldn't be surprised if things aren't working very well, and it continues for the foreseeable future.